# PHP get Element(s) from (parsed) HTML

Tags: php, html

i currently try to make an Website mobile friendly. The Website is not hosted on the same Webserver, so i have to load the document to my Server's PHP to prevent the Same Origin Problem in Javascript. Then i parse the Elements (such as User Posts) into my prepared jQuery Mobile document using jQuery's Ajax.

The Problem is, the Website is using an old Forum software, that uses tables and does not set ID's into the HTML Elements. Another Problem is, that i send the full Document (1.1 MB) to the Mobile app from PHP. So, basically i load the Website like:

```
$this->url = $url; //website URL
$this->file = file_get_contents($this->url); //load the document

echo $this->file;
```

and get the Element i need, and post parse it into the Mobile App:

```
window.beitraege = $j(htmldoc).find('#lastthreads9'); //find the latest Posts
$j("#beitraege").html(window.beitraege); //parse them into a div
```

So, in order to not send to the Mobile App 1.1 MB of unnecessary Data, i'd like to only send the Element with, the for example, ID "lastthreads9".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar to this to extract a  tag from an HTML source using the HTML DOM in php....

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($this->file); // call in your HTML source

// get title
$title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title");
```

You might need to tweak it a bit, but you may be able to find your HTML ID this way using something like getElementById in place of getElementsByTagName.